# Confusion about fileds and get methods in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, properties, field, getter-setter

Since A is a property and not a field, does that mean that A and B are functioning **exactly** the same way? If not, what are their difference?

```
class myClass(val x : Int, val y : Int){
    
    val A = x * y
    
    val B :Int
        get(){
            return x * y
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific example, a property with a backing field (`A`) and a property without a backing field (`B`) work exactly the same, because `x` and `y` are `val`s and their values can't be reassigned - no matter how many times you compute `x * y` it'll always return the same result. But consider the following program:

```
class myClass(var x : Int, val y : Int){

    val A = x * y
    
    val B :Int
        get(){
            return x * y
        }
}

fun main() {
    val myClass = MyClass(x = 2, y = 3)
    println(myClass.A) // 6
    println(myClass.B) // 6
    
    myClass.x = 4
    println(myClass.A) // 6
    println(myClass.B) // 12
}
```

`x` is a `var` now, which means that its value can be changed. The value of `A` has already been computed when the instance of `MyClass` was created, so changing the value of `x` has no effect on the value of `A`. But since accessing `B` executes the body of its getter every time, a change in the value of `x` will affect the result of the next call to that getter.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that because by accessing A, actually a get Method is called, that the x * y was recomputed every time too

Comment: Doesn’t A compile to use a backing field (so it uses more memory) and B evaluate the multiplication every time it’s accessed (so it uses more CPU)? By usually trivial amounts (which might not be trivial at scale), but I wouldn’t call that exactly the same.

Comment: @Tenfour04, valid point. Guess we should've defined what "exactly the same" means first.